# Помогите решить логическую задачу

Tags: python, c#

Санта-Клаус решил разобрать свою клавиатуру, чтобы её почистить. После того, как он поставил все клавиши обратно, он с ужасом понял, что что-то не так: некоторые пары клавиш перепутаны между собой! Таким образом, Санта-Клаус подозревает, что каждая клавиша либо стоит на своём месте, либо заняла место другой, а та другая — на месте первой.

Для того, чтобы убедиться в этом, найти ошибку и восстановить верное расположение, Санта-Клаус набрал текст своей любимой скороговорки, смотря только на надписи на клавиатуре.

Вам даны любимая скороговорка Санта-Клауса и строка, которая получилась в результате набора. Определите, какие пары клавиш Санта-Клаус мог перепутать. Каждая клавиша должна принадлежать не более чем одной паре перепутанных клавиш.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код ваших попыток решить задачу. И опишите что не получается. Иначе вопрос закроют.

Comment: > если ввести строки ударившись головой об клавиатуру, то не правильно считает, я не понимаю почему - мне кажется, что, вообще говоря, условие "каждая клавиша либо стоит на своём месте, либо заняла место другой, а та другая — на месте первой" не будет выполняться для произвольного искажения текста. Это довольно искусственное условие - что каждая клавиша может быть перепутана только с "одной другой". Поэтому и может не работиать для происвольного "текста с ошибками"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так - делаете словарь, и для каждой пары символов на соответствующих позициях записываете в словарь `(a:b)`, где `a` - меньший по алфавиту символ, если данный ключ ещё не использован.

Если по ключу а найдено другое значение -всё, приехали, здравствуйте, бабушка, выводим `-1`

Если такое же - ничего не делаем.

В конце вывести пары из словаря, кроме содержащих одинаковые элементы `(a:a)`

Ввиду ограниченности алфавита можно просто массив на 26 элементов использовать.

```
def keyboard(s, u):
    dict = {}
    for i in range(len(s)):
        cs = s[i]
        cu = u[i]
        if cs > cu:
            cs, cu = cu, cs
        if cs in dict.keys():
            t = dict[cs]
            if t != cu:
                print(-1)
                return
        else:
            dict[cs] = cu
    # здесь  можно очистить словарь от дубликатов, чтобы счётчик вывести
    for cs, cu in dict.items():
        if cs != cu:
            print(cs, cu)

keyboard("helloworld", "ehoolwlroz")
keyboard("helloworld", "ehoolwlrzz")
keyboard("helloworld", "ehoolwlrlz")
keyboard("gndggadlmdefgejidmmcglbjdcmglncfmbjjndjcibnjbabfab", "fihffahlmhogfojnhmmcflkjhcmflicgmkjjihjcnkijkakgak")
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую понять ваш вариант и написать в программе)).

Comment: Спасибо огромное!